# STM32H7 QuadSPI CMSIS Read

Tags: stm32, memory, cmsis, qspi

So, I am trying to access an APS6404 IC (PSRAM) with QSPI on STM32H7 (currently in single-line mode). When I am writing to it, everything seems fine, but as soon as I read - the FIFO is empty and the read operation from the QUADSPI->DR register waits forever (QUADSPI is busy forever). FIFO FSIZE is zero. What am I doing wrong in my code? I don't think it's a problem with the IC, since it's essentially SPI and it should always return something.

```
void qspi_init() {
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOB->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE6, 0b10 << GPIO_MODER_MODE6_Pos);
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOD->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE12, 0b10 << GPIO_MODER_MODE12_Pos);
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOE->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE2, 0b10 << GPIO_MODER_MODE2_Pos);
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOD->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE0, 0b10 << GPIO_MODER_MODE0_Pos);
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOB->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE2, 0b10 << GPIO_MODER_MODE2_Pos);
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOD->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE13, 0b10 << GPIO_MODER_MODE13_Pos);


    MODIFY_REG(RCC->D1CCIPR, RCC_D1CCIPR_QSPISEL, (0b00) << RCC_D1CCIPR_QSPISEL_Pos); // PLL1Q as clock source
    RCC->AHB3ENR |= RCC_AHB3ENR_QSPIEN;
    QUADSPI->CR = (255 << QUADSPI_CR_PRESCALER_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CR_FSEL_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CR_DFM_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CR_SSHIFT_Pos);
    QUADSPI->DCR = (22 << QUADSPI_DCR_FSIZE_Pos) | (7 << QUADSPI_DCR_CSHT_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_DCR_CKMODE_Pos); // 8MB, max hold time, CLK Low when NCS=1
    QUADSPI->CR |= QUADSPI_CR_EN;
    QUADSPI->DLR = 0;

    // Send reset: 0x66, 0x99

    QUADSPI->CCR =  (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_DDRM_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_SIOO_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_FMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_DMODE_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_DCYC_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_ABMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b10 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADSIZE_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADMODE_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_IMODE_Pos)
                    | (0x66 << QUADSPI_CCR_INSTRUCTION_Pos);
    WAITNBIT(QUADSPI->SR, QUADSPI_SR_BUSY);
    QUADSPI->CCR =  (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_DDRM_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_SIOO_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_FMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_DMODE_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_DCYC_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_ABMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b10 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADSIZE_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADMODE_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_IMODE_Pos)
                    | (0x99 << QUADSPI_CCR_INSTRUCTION_Pos);
    WAITNBIT(QUADSPI->SR, QUADSPI_SR_BUSY);
}

void qspi_write1(uint32_t addr, uint8_t b) {
    QUADSPI->DLR = 0;
    QUADSPI->CCR =  (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_DDRM_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_SIOO_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_FMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_DMODE_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_DCYC_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_ABMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b10 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADSIZE_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADMODE_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_IMODE_Pos)
                    | (0x02 << QUADSPI_CCR_INSTRUCTION_Pos);

    QUADSPI->AR = addr;
    QUADSPI->DR = b;
    WAITNBIT(QUADSPI->SR, QUADSPI_SR_BUSY);
}

uint8_t qspi_read1(uint32_t addr) {
    QUADSPI->SR &= ~QUADSPI_SR_TCF;
    QUADSPI->DLR = 0;
    QUADSPI->CCR =  (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_DDRM_Pos) | (0 << QUADSPI_CCR_SIOO_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_FMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_DMODE_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_DCYC_Pos) | (0b00 << QUADSPI_CCR_ABMODE_Pos)
                    | (0b10 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADSIZE_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_ADMODE_Pos) | (0b01 << QUADSPI_CCR_IMODE_Pos)
                    | (0x03 << QUADSPI_CCR_INSTRUCTION_Pos);

    QUADSPI->AR = addr;
    uint32_t sr;
    uint8_t data = 0;
    do {
        sr = QUADSPI->SR;
        if(sr & QUADSPI_SR_FTF) {
            data = QUADSPI->DR;
        }
    } while (sr & QUADSPI_SR_BUSY);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've forgot to set up the pins alternate functions. For some reason, QSPI doesn't just put out garbage, but stops working completely in this case.